# Since moving to a VPS I keep getting 500 internal server errors in GPI

Tags: apache2

I moved from shared hosting to VPS a few days ago. I myself raised that VPS and it is Ubuntu 16.04 based, with Apache and some virtual hosts, it's lightweight with almost no extensive software on it. All of my sites works just fine and I can change them and surf in them without any problem.

My problem is that when I run [a GPI test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to my site, **about 50% of the time** (about 50% of the tests) I get `500 Internal Server Error`.

My question is, why would that happen? What's worth checking?

`sudo cat /var/log/apache2/access.log`, brings this:

```
::1 - - [05/Dec/2016:11:07:56 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

`sudo nano /var/log/apache2/error.log` shows basically only this error which is very long, too much long for here I guess, so I'll paste only it's critical part:

```
[Mon Dec 05 14:53:26.574836 2016] [:error] [pid 31711] [client 66.249.88.155:46289] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Database\\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: "SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction:
```

Comment: My first check is to see if I have `php_value`. And then remove them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Those are, in my case, often the problem causer. If I remove those from the htaccess, 500 error is gone.

Comment: I didn't touch the .htaccess, I never added anything to it. Even if these are there and I'll remove them, they might come back after CMS update...

Comment: @Martijn If there was a problem with `php_value` in `.htaccess` then you'd get the error 100% of the time, not 50% of the time (and just from Google PageSpeed Insights) as stated. (You can't necessarily just "remove them" from .htaccess either.)

Comment: You need to check your error log.

Comment: I've updated the question. I could supply more data but this is all I have for now. If you will give me a direction I'll try to supply that...

Comment: The IP address in the second error is of Google crawler.

Answer (score 1):

Your first log entry shows Apache returning a *200* Ok, not a 500 Server Error.

You can find plenty of information [online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22deadlock+found+when+trying+to+get+lock%22&ia=web) about the error message from `error.log`.  A deadlock means that two different queries are attempting to gain a database lock at the same time and are dependent on each other finishing.  This is likely an issue with poorly written code, and has always existed, but Google is requesting pages at a higher rate than you normally get through organic traffic, causing it to manifest.

If you look at the full stack trace (that you haven't included here), that should give you some good places to start looking in your code for problematic queries.  You can also run `show full processlist\G` and `show engine innodb status` in a MySQL shell while this is happening to try and catch some information about the queries.